# Can と AND や be used in a sentence for a list of things

Tags: particles, syntax

I have been reading about using と and や.

Now, I [understand the basic idea](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17376/difference-using-%E3%81%A8-and-%E3%82%84-%EF%BD%9E-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9) that や is for a list where the list is not all-inclusive. と on the other hand essentially informs the listener that "only these things are what I mean."

Are there any times where the "and" や and と would both be used in a sentence? Specifically for a list of things?

> 趣味がスキーやゴルフや英語と日本語の勉強やカラオケです。

as a possible (and poor?) example. If I wanted to say in the example above "My hobbies are skiing, golf, studying English and Japanese, and karaoke."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example sentence I think is a little clumsy, but short answer: yes. と in a case similar to your example would just be a component in one of the noun phrases that makes up your list. For the sentence, however, 趣味はスキーやゴルフ、英語と日本語の勉強、カラオケなどです would be better. Points to take away:

- 趣味は not 趣味が.
- When making longer lists of things, Japanese typically works, unsurprisingly perhaps, in the reverse of English, with further conjunctions omitted.