# How to use と with three or more nouns?

Tags: grammar, usage, particle-と

I just started learning Japanese and I recently learned something like:

> このかめらと、あのらじおをください。
>   (Please give me this camera and that radio.)

Note that I have not learned Katakana yet so sorry for the Hiragana up there.

So, what if I want three or more objects at the same distance. For example, I want the camera, TV and the radio that is right in front of me.

Can I say something like:

> このかめら、てれびと、らじおをください。

To omit some "and (と)"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34183/listing-three-or-more-items & https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17732/can-と-and-や-be-used-in-a-sentence-for-a-list-of-things. In casual condition "や" is used more often and other "と" replaced with just comma.

Comment: ^ `In casual condition "や" is used more often and other "と" replaced with just comma` -- 電気屋で買い物するとき「このカメラ**や**テレビ(を)ください」「このカメラ**や**テレビ**や**ラジオ(を)ください。」「このカメラ、テレビ、ラジオ(を)ください」って言わないでしょ。（あと、電気屋で話すときコンマ見えないでしょ）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> この[カメラ]{かめら}**と**[テレビ]{てれび}**と**[ラジオ]{らじお}（を）ください。

would sound okay when talking to a store clerk while shopping.

---

「AとBとC」 sounds a tiny bit more casual/conversational than 「A、BとC」「A、B、C」. You can say/write...

> [趣味]{しゅみ}は[ピアノ]{ぴあの}、[読書]{どくしょ}と[映画鑑賞]{えいがかんしょう}です。
>   My hobbies are playing piano, reading, and watching movies.
>   [首相]{しゅしょう}は、[スペイン]{すぺいん}、[フランス]{ふらんす}、[ベルギー]{べるぎー}を[訪問]{ほうもん}する[予定]{よてい}。
>   Prime Minister is visiting Spain, France, and Belgium.

(You can also use 「A、BそしてC」「A、B[及]{およ}びC」 etc. which sound more formal.)

Comment: NHK news also seems to enjoy the pattern AとB、C.